# process file to 'staggered' format

Tags: bash, echo

I am attempting to write a bash script that returns all of the three word phrases of a file, followed by a newline. An example would look like this:

```
input : This is a file with words in it

output:
this is a 
is a file
a file with
file with words
with words in
words in it
```

Notably, it requires a concept for 'word' which can, for this purpose, be seen as being denoted by whitespace. Additionally, in it... is not a three word phrase. Ultimately, I would like to take files formatted like this, and sort uniq them together, but this step is hanging me up, as it seems to require some ability to 'tell what's next' in a file, and also not go out of bounds in the last few.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `awk` and `tr` (to join multiple lines):

```
tr '\n' ' ' < file.txt | awk '{ for(i=3; i<=NF; i++) { print $(i-2) " " $(i-1) " " $i }}'
```

Comment: This neatly figures out the idea of 'looking forward' that I was having trouble with, with the i-2, i-1 bits. Thank you, That is simpler than I would have thought of.

Comment: +1. Smart to start the loop at index 3 rather than doing arithmetic on the end condition. Readable.

Answer (score -1):

If the file isn't "big" you can use `for` to loop over the words in it:

```
for word in $(cat input.txt); do echo $word; done
```

If the file is too big for that, you can use `read` to read a line at a time, and then `for` to iterate over the words in the line:

```
while read line; do for word in $line; do echo $word; done; done < input.txt
```

For the body of the loop, just keep track of "last_word" and "word_before_that", and as long as all three are non-empty you should be fine.

Comment: `while read -ra line; do for word in "${line[@]}"; do ...`. If you still wanted to follow your same idea, `for word in $line` would have done fine.

Comment: The -a arg to read is required for that to work, since that is what causes read to split the line into an array rather than a scalar.

Comment: @jordanm D'oh. I've paid closer attention this time, and have fixed my answer.  Thanks for the corrections.